# Scanning the whole code if $? = 0 or 1

Tags: linux, shell

I understand that to check for error level in Linux can be done by using `$?`. The thing is that the `$?` value is reset if one of the commands is successfully performed, even if the previous command failed. The code I use for testing as below:

```
cd /vobs/test2/test3 
if [ $2 = "R" ]; then 
     mv missing ~/missing2
 echo "Created"
```

Assuming that `mv missing ~/missing2` failed the `$?` should be equal to `1` but due to the last command `echo "Created"` is performed the `$?` will be equal to `0`. How to perform a scan for the code above so that the moment that `$?=1` it will execute `exit 1` command. I can perform if else for every command execute but it is not the best way to perform, is it? I need some advice on this, please.

Comment: Note that it would be helpful if you showed a working fragment of the shell script. You've missed out the `fi`, which makes it hard to guess what you really had in mind — was the `echo` inside the body of the `if` or outside it? The indentation doesn't help us either. In general, you should enclose `"$2"` in quotes (but it wouldn't matter if you omitted the quotes around `"R"`, though I'd keep them there for consistency). If you're worried about a command failing, you can test it: `if mv missing ~/missing; then echo "Created"; else echo "Failed to create"; fi`, etc. Or you can use `set -e`.

Comment: Best practices are generally to build your error handling in a manner appropriate to the immediate script at hand. `die() { (( $# )) && echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }` is a handy utility function for this purpose, followed by uses like `cd /vobs/test2/test3 || die`.

Comment: ...`set -e` can be used, but requires a fair bit of care and caution; see my link in a comment to the existing answer.

Comment: Hi , @CharlesDuffy what kind of caution should I take  when using the set -e inside a shell script ?The script is going to be used in Jenkins.

Comment: @RandyWong, read BashFAQ #105, linked elsewhere, and be sure you fully understand why all its examples occur; then write your script with that knowledge in mind. (Otherwise, if you find that too full of caveats and version-specific details, use `|| die` and similar idioms instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exit on the first failing command using `set -e`. This is part of an unofficial "[strict bash mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)":

- `set -e`

  To exit on all errors.
- `set -o pipefail`

  To fail on the first issue in a pipeline rather than only last one.
- `set -u`

  To fail on access to undefined variables.

Comment: Aside: `pipefail` is pretty much universally considered a good idea; the others are more controversial, whereas perl's "strict mode" is more uniformly considered a best practice. For the technical issues underlying one piece of that controversy, see BashFAQ #105: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: ...not that `pipefail` can't act as a gotcha at times too; consider piping to `grep -q`, and the item before it in the pipeline getting a `SIGPIPE` and exiting nonzero after that first match is found.

Comment: Hi ,I tested the set -e and it works .I have a few concern about set -e?Does it has the same function as if [ $?==1 ] exit 1 ?As for the pipefaiI I read the link that you posted .It says that if the $? value is 1 and there are passed command executed like echo "" it will return the $? as 1 instead of 0 ?But when I test it on my code that has 3 or more command , it gives me 0 at the last echo if the 2nd command fails .So pipefail only can check for 1 or last command for $?  instead the whole code ?

Comment: More like `if [ $? != 0 ] exit 1`. The actual code doesn't really matter. `pipefail` is for pipes only. `false | false` fails on the first false with pipefail and on the last without pipefail.

Comment: Can @viraptor provide an example of how `pipefail` will work if there are more command in the script ? Because I don't quite understand when you state that it is only for pipes only .

Comment: Try `(exit 3) | (exit 0) ; echo $?` with and without pipefail set. You'll see the difference. It's also explained in `man bash`